# Group where clause use

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
ItemNo  ItemMarker
100007  3
100007  4
100007  5
100007  6
```

I have a query and I want to exclude all item no that has ItemMarker 6, which means I dont want to see 3,4,5.

When I use a filter where ItemMArker = 6, it is still returning 3,4,5 rows but I want any Item that has marker 6 to all be excluded regardless of the ItemMarker no.

Comment: Tag the dbms used. And show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 
                  from t t2
                  where t2.itemno = t.itemno and t2.itemmarket = 6
                 );
```